# mouse move wakes up sleeping mac.. how to prevent?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake

When the cleaning man has been by my desk then my computer wakes up from sleep. How can I make it insensitive to mouse movements?

Comment: is it a bluetooth mouse?

Comment: the mouse is connected with a cable. A bluetooth device.. hmm, good idea.

Comment: Yeah with bluetooth you have this option. Not with wired :(

Comment: You have this option with a wired mouse. Unplug it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a bluetooth mouse you can disable it waking the computer by unchecking

```
Allow Bluetooth devices to wake this computer.
```

in System Preferences - Bluetooth - Advanced

This will also effect the wireless keyboard waking the Mac so you will need to use the power button to wake it.